# Regarding application deployement in Azure using visual studio

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have signed up for a free azure account. I am trying to deploy my application in azure through visual studio 2017,but the drop down box for the subscriptions is always blank and I'm not able to go forward. I have also restarted visual studio after my subscription.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any service you subscribed to?

Comment: can you login to the portal.azure.com using the same account? does it work?

Comment: yes,it does work when I login.

Answer (score 0):

It often caused by cache issue. You need to sign out and remove all the account from Visual Studio Account setting panel. After that, please **restart your Visual Studio** and login your Azure account again.

[image]

If it also doesn't work for your, you could publish your web application to Azure Web App by downloading profile from Azure portal. Steps below are for your reference.

1. Create Azure Web App on Azure portal.
2. Get publish profile from Azure portal.

[image]

3. Choose import profile when deploying your web application using Web Deploy.

[image]